# onkeyenterred does'nt work with flutter_geofire

Tags: android, ios, flutter

var driverLocation = fbDataBaseRef.reference().child("DriversAvailable").path;
Geofire.initialize(driverLocation);
var query = Geofire.queryAtLocation(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude, radius);
query.listen((map) {

```
  var event = map["callBack"];

  if(event != null){

    print("//////////////////////// \n \n \n \n");
    print(event);
    print("\n\n\n\n");
    print("//////////////////////// \n \n \n \n");

    switch(event){

      case Geofire.onGeoQueryReady:

        getClosestDriver();
        print(event['result']);
        radius++;
        break;

      case Geofire.onKeyEntered:
        print("-------------------------------------------------");
        if(found == false){
          found = true;
          driverID = event['key'];
          print('********************');
          print(driverID);

          var dbReference = fbDataBaseRef.reference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverID);
          dbReference.child("ok");

        }
        // keysRetrieved.add(callback["key"]);
        break;

      case Geofire.onKeyExited:
        // keysRetrieved.remove(callback["key"]);
        break;

      case Geofire.onKeyMoved:
      // Update your key's location
        break;

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried differents things but switch statement never exec onkeyenterred but it execute onGeoQueryReady as you can see i printed multiple times but nothing in output so please have you a solution for me and the easiest solution possible

Comment: For me the `Geofire.queryAtLocation` is never called , how did u get this working ? Did you do anything specific with the path or added something extra in rule ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68364109/no-response-while-calling-geofire-initialize-on-firebase-realtime-database

Comment: @PannamT - even I faced the same issue in my iOS app on my mac air m1, but I was able to resolve it by running "Flutterfire Configure" from the mac terminal from my project directory and then copied the updated "GoogleService-info.plist" once again to Xcode runner of the respective project and then finally added the following lines in main.dart:

`import 'firebase_options.dart';

await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );`